# I required veriable worksheets in formula Cells(4, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",sheet2!R[1]C-Sheet2!RC,"""")"

Tags: vba

Pl anyone help me to correct my formula.
Actually i am working on my personal project.
I want to set variable worksheets in following formula of `vba` code.

```
Cells(4, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",sheet2!R[1]C-Sheet2!RC,"""")"
```

i want get details from variable worksheet instead of `sheet2`. cell reference are same only variable is worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my question by correcting code as below

Ques code: Cells(4, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",sheet2!R[1]C-Sheet2!RC,"""")"

Ans Code: Cells(4, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>""""," & ws & "!R[1]C-" & ws & "!RC,"""")"